# Visual Studio Project template with a wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-templates

I am looking for an example of how to build a visual studio project template that contains a wizard. The wizard will be used to collect additional choices from the user to customize the selected template.

I figured out how to build templates, but I don't know how to launch a wizard or how to write these choices into the source of the project the template is building.

I have been searching (Google) and I do find some documentation from Microsoft about this, but it is very confusing.

I am looking for a good working example (c# if possible) that I can learn from. I have not been able to find any.

I was hoping that someone would know of a good tutorial on video and or some example projects to get me started in the right direction with this project.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old blog entry that details how to do this:

[Creating a VSIX Deployable Project (or Item) Template with Custom Wizard Support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsx/archive/2014/06/10/creating-a-vsix-deployable-project-or-item-template-with-custom-wizard-support.aspx)

or you could just download and use [The VSX Template Wizard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsx/archive/2015/04/11/the-vsx-template-wizard.aspx), if you're using VS 2013, to give you a good jump start.